# Arraylist is not getting updated in recursion correctly

Tags: java, recursion

Below is my function which gives all the possibilities that the elements in a given array sums up to a specific target. I am able to print the lists, however the result list is not getting updated.

```
public List<List<Integer>> helper(List<List<Integer>> res, int[] c, int l, int h, int target, List<Integer> temp){
        if(target == 0){
            res.add(temp);
            System.out.println(temp);
            return res;
        }
        if(target < c[l]){
            return res; 
        }
        for(int i = l; i <=h; i++){
            temp.add(c[i]);
            res = helper(res, c,i,h,target-c[i], temp);
            temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

res is arraylist of empty arraylists in the end, but the 5th line prints the temp arraylist correctly.

The function is called as below.

```
List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
res = helper(res,candidates, 0, candidates.length-1, target, temp);
```

Example:
Given array = [1,2,3], target = 6

stdout:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3]

res is [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Comment: what's your input and what results did your debugging show?

Comment: Updated with the inputs and results

Answer (score 4):

This is standard **pass by reference** against **pass by value** issue.

You are adding a reference of a `temp` to the `res` object so whenever value of `temp` changed (which does within `for loop` in your program), it changes value of an instance in `res` as well so at the end when all elements has been removed from the `temp`, list becomes empty and then it changes all value within `res` to an empty list.

Change your **helper method first if condition** as below and it should work:

```
if(target == 0){
  ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(temp);
  res.add(copy);
  return res;
}
```

**Explanation**

Instead of adding a reference of a `temp` to `res`, we are creating a simple copy of `temp` and then add it to `res`.

This prevents value being overwritten with the new object value.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are adding temp to `res`. So everytime you are adding same `temp` reference to `res` list. In the end `temp` will be an empty list so all the values in `res` will be empty as they are pointing to same `temp` reference.
If you pass new list for temp, you can fix this problem.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> helper(List<List<Integer>> res, int[] c, int l, int h, int target, List<Integer> temp){
        if(target == 0){
            res.add(temp);
            System.out.println(temp);
            return res;
        }
        if(target < c[l]){
            return res; 
        }
        for(int i = l; i <=h; i++){
            temp.add(c[i]);
            res = helper(res, c,i,h,target-c[i], new ArrayList<Integer>(temp));
            temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: what is called a shallow copy? adding a reference to a list sure not - https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/85421

Comment: Actually its not a shallow copy. Its just holding the reference of temp. Check updated answer.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I was considering some other case which was not valid. So I corrected the answer.